# How to log transaction begin, commit and rollbacks of Spring JDBC DataSourceTransactionManager?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-jdbc

I need to check the transaction commands of Spring JDBC.

How can I log the transaction begin, rollback and commit automatically called from Spring JDBC DataSourceTransactionManager with log4j?

Comment: What is it you want to log and why do you need to check the transaction commands? Spring doesn't issue any, the jdbc driver does that, Spring only provided a wrapper around it and you yourself mark the start and end of the transaction.

Comment: I need to check the real transaction opening and closing, currently I neet to use the database general log and it is not very handy. The trx manager provide commits and rollbacks, why you said I mark the end of transaction? If Spring is only a wrapper of JDBC, how can I log them from JDBC driver?

Comment: If you need the logs, just enable debug logging for the transaction package. The start/end you need to mark with `@Transactional` you need to tell spring what is your transactional boundary.